# Script : check 8th field of /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to check if the 8th field of /etc/shadow of a username has no entry.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat < "users.txt")
do
sudo grep -w $i /etc/shadow | awk -F: "$8 == ' '" | cut -d: -f1 ;
done
```

But this is the error that i get when i execute the script

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ==
```

Answer (score 0):

awk syntax for this purpose would be:

```
awk -F 'delim' '$n1 == "text" {print $n2}'

sudo grep -w $i /etc/shadow |  awk -F':' '$8 == " "  {print $0}'
```

FYI: /etc/shadow does not contain spaces between colons. so if cat shows
bin:*:1:1:::::::

you should run `$8 == ""`
note that there is no space.

If n2 is 0, you'd return the entire row. Hope this helps!

Comment: n1 and n2 ARE 0 since they're uninitialized awk variables being used in a numeric context.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can be greatly simplified, typically using grep and awk on one line indicates that you're overthinking things. Invoking one command instead of three ...

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat < "users.txt")
do
sudo awk -F: -v user=$i '$1==user && $8==""{print $1}' /etc/shadow
done
```